# "Order of magnitude" for changes in prefix

Tags: terminology

Order of magnitude usually denotes a change of a factor of 10.  Is there a similar term for a change by a factor of 1000?

For example:

Kb -> Mb

Tb -> Gb

Edit:  I agree that you can just say "three orders of magnitude" but I am wondering if there is a more concise or appropriate term.

Comment: For a "math-literate" audience, *"Mb is greater than Kb by three orders of magnitude"* is about as concise as it gets. For the rest of the world, you just have to say *"Mb is a thousand times greater than Kb"*.

Comment: Of course 1Mb is actually 1024Mb, not 1000Mb. But "order of magnitude" in informal English tends to imply some level of approximation.

Comment: While I agree that "thousandfold" is probably the clearest answer, I've also seen a factor of 1000 referred to as an "engineering order of magnitude", coming from the ubiquitous engineering use of SI prefixes which, as you note, go up or down by factors of 1000.

Comment: @slim You wanted to say "Of course 1Gb (!!!) is actually 1024Mb", didn't you?

Comment: "Of course 1Mb is actually 1024Mb, not 1000Mb." Hello, what! I would be thoroughly glad to get 1000Mb for 1Mb, better if it's 1024.

Comment: @slim See also, my answer below.

Comment: @Stephen Gah. Careless typo.

Comment: Erik, I've never heard the "Engineering Order of Magnitude" phrase, nor could I find it in a google search.  I know that scientific calculators sometimes use "Engineering Notation" in which the exponent is always a multiple of 3, but to an engineer an order of magnitude is clearly a factor of 10, not 1000.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider *[thousandfold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thousandfold)*.  The example in wiktionary is:

> The changes to the algorithm resulted in a thousandfold increase in efficiency, earning the engineer a small brass plaque.

wiktionary also shows a plural, [thousandfolds](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thousandfolds), but for purposes of approximation, go with *thousandsfold* instead.
Example: "There was a thousandsfold increase in consumption when they added ingredient X."

*Edit:*  Note that [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thousandfold%2Cthousandfolds%2Cthousandsfold&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows little use of either of *thousandfolds* or *thousandsfold* by comparison with *thousandfold*.  Here are some examples of use of *thousandsfold* evinced in google-books [references](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thousandsfold%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en):

- "...the quantities will be reduced thousandsfold from the concentrations in the originally polluted areas." - ["Nature out of place", Van Driesche & Van Driesche](http://books.google.com/books?id=SjymkFK4rp4C&pg=PA91&dq=%22thousandsfold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FobzTs61BaSRiQf5op2fAQ&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22thousandsfold%22&f=false), 2004
- "By introducing pigs, rats, domestic plants ... they raised the biological colonization rate thousandsfold." - ["The future of life", E. O. Wilson](http://books.google.com/books?id=VUJplhLArbwC&pg=PA46&dq=%22thousandsfold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FobzTs61BaSRiQf5op2fAQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22thousandsfold%22&f=false), 2003
- "... as if ... from the distance of the Falls of the Clyde (our little Scottish Niagara) with the body of water there thousandsfold increased..." - ["Across Western Waves: America for Modern Athenians ...", Arthur Giles](http://books.google.com/books?id=nuy5G29sJFcC&pg=PA26&dq=%22thousandsfold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FobzTs61BaSRiQf5op2fAQ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22thousandsfold%22&f=false) , 2007 reprinting of a previous-century book

Comment: +1 Also twofold, sevenfold, tenfold, hundredfold, other numbers.

Comment: -1 for **thousandsfold.** I'll reverse the downvote if you correct that!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've added comments re "thousandsfold" usage in several books.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: The original publication date of "Across Western Waves: ..." was 1848

Comment: @jwpat7: Not any more, I guess. Even in the explicit case **several thousandfold** where plural definitely applies, including that "s" is [below the radar](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=several+thousandsfold%2Cseveral+thousandfold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in NGrams. You think it's okay - but I don't, and apparently the majority are with me. But ELU is nothing if not democratic, and you don't need my vote to be winning here (though I imagine it's more for *thousandfold* than for the non-standard plural).

Comment: ...I'll also just add that [several tenfold](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=several+tenfold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), though rare, does actually occur. On the other hand, the "word" **tensfold** seems to all intents and purposes not to exist at all.

Answer (score 5):

"Three orders of magnitude".

Or less precisely "orders of magnitude".

Or, still imprecise, and for larger orders "several orders of magnitude".

Note that for many people who are not mathematically literate an "order of magnitude" just means "a lot".

Comment: It's not just interpretation by readers who aren't mathematically literate; it's that the phrase is often used metaphorically. *That's an order of magnitude better* might mean *a lot* depending on the context. This use seems reasonably common, for example, in [news](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&btnmeta_news_search=1&q=order+of+magnitude&oq=order+of+magnitude), where phrases like *his changes of mind are greater than Mr Romney's by an order of magnitude* appear, and even science-related articles say things like *roughly an order of magnitude*.

Answer (score 0):

Could we say a megabyte is a kilobyte grand? My coinage, though.

As an aside,
[New IEC Standard](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/calculate/)
megabyte (decimal)  MB  (=) 1000 kilobytes